# Distinguishing homotopy types of the long line and the really long line

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

We define the $LI$ to be the long line (that is gluing $\omega_1$ copies of the space $(0,1)$ end to end), and similarly we define $LLI$ the really long line to be the gluing of $\omega_2$ copies of $(0,1)$ end to end.

Now for obvious cardinality reasons $LI$ is not homeomorphic to $LLI$. Intution would lead me to believe that they aren't homotopic either (because $LI$ isn't homotopic to the ordinary line $\mathbb{R}$), but I have no idea how to back my intuition up with a proof.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just glue $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ intervals instead? That way you don't have to use the axiom of choice.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, my understanding of such topics is shady, I thought you needed AoC to construct them. Feel free to edit my question for it to not involve AoC

Comment: $\omega_1$ is perfectly well-defined in the absence of choice, it's just the set of all countable ordinals. You need the axiom of choice (and the continuum hypothesis) to biject this set with $\mathbb{R}$. But that isn't essential to the definition of the long line anyway (and Wikipedia defines it using $\omega_1$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You need more than the axiom of choice to make those two sets bijective.

Comment: One difference between $LI$ and $LLI$ which means that they cannot be homotopy equivalent is that $LLI$ is a not path connected. For example it contains no path from $1$ to $\omega_1$ (as such a path would map onto all of $LI$).

Comment: I am a bit confused as I don't think $LI$ is pathconnected either, e.g. by taking two point which lie in copies with uncountably many copies of $(0,1)$ in between them.

Comment: The points of $\omega_1$ are the countable ordinals. Thus in $LI$, to go from (say) $1$ to any other point, one only needs to pass through countably many copies of $[0,1]$ (note that $(0,1)$ has no endpoints to glue with).

Comment: Oh then I think I was confused about how long the long line is, and which ordinals are in $\omega_1$. Then I think I was wondering how to distinguish between the $\omega_2$ long line and the $\omega_3$ long line. But I am not comfortable enough with $\omega_i$ and thing like that to be sure... Maybe @QiaochuYuan you could edit my question appropriately so that my lines are "long enough" without involving AoC?